# Resource Route linked to incorrect action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am just starting out with rails and have run into some difficulties. I am trying to create a basic form that will add a new entry to the "Main" database. When I submit the form, instead of running "new" it appears to be trying to run "update", which according to the documentation should be called by      /photos/:id

There error I am getting on the browser is

Unknown action

The action 'update' could not be found for AdminController

Controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @post = Main.create
    end

    def new

    end
end
```

index.erb.html:

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => { :action => "new" }, :html => {:class => "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :entry, :size => "60x12" %>
  <%= f.submit "New" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
Tasks::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => "Main#index"

   resources :main
   resources :admin
```

Comment: Form is now working, but another problem has popped up

`
<%= form_for @post, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:class => "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.text_area :entry, :size => "60x12" %>
   <%= f.submit "Create" %>
 <% end %>`

It appears to be creating an empty entry, do I need to pass the variables on to the create method?

` def create
 @post = Main.create
 end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails `new` is supposed to **show** the form to enter a new item.
`edit` is for **showing** the form to edit an existing item.

The form data is then `POST`ed to `mains_url` if it's a new item or `PUT` if its an exitsing item.
`POST` is routed to the `create` action.
`PUT` is routed to the `update` action.

So, to create an item, you have to implement `create`, to update it, you have to implement `update`

see

```
rake routes
```